# Git sees only master branch on remote repo

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I am tryoung to use git under Win7 and get some strange problems.

I have a TFS repository with many branches.
I need to download to my home computer and work on a branch named 'model'.
So I type in command line

```
git init
git remote add origin https://tfs.company_name.com/tfs/DS/ProjectName/_git/project_name
git pull
```

it downloades files for the master branch and after that I see only branch 'master' (`git branch --all`)

if I add another origin

```
git remote add model https://tfs.company_name.com/tfs/DS/ProjectName/_git/project_name
```

i still see only master branch

`git checkout model` doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does `git branch -a` gives you? Do you see the `model` branch returned?

Comment: it gives an empty line

Comment: Try doing a `git fetch --all` and see if the `git branch` returns you the `model` branch then?